# iOS Remoted Simulator on windows

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

iOS Remoted Simulator in windows. My visual studio connected to mac successfully and also all Simulator show in visual studio on windows but problem is when clicked on any Simulator its just connecting window show a long time but not connect

Comment: Have you first tried connecting a monitor to the mac, putting visual studio mac and your source code there, doing the build there, making sure simulator works in that simpler case?

Comment: First, you need to exclude the connect problem After that, that's maybe the simulator problem.
This is the official docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to exclude the connecting problem. If it is not, that's maybe the simulator problem(official docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/).

The simulator list shows on visual studio, can't make sure you pair to the mac successfully, it's maybe the cache. You should check the 'Pair to Mac' icon in visual studio, make sure it's green, as it will check the connection situation regularly. You can click it for the connection details.

If the 'Pair to Mac' icon is green, and shows a connected mac as you click it for details.
That's maybe the simulator problems. You'd better check it on mac. But it's really a small probability event.

And This is a standard solution to this problem:
Some suggestions :

Upgrade everything to the latest (VS for mac , VS for windows , XCode ).

Restart PC and visual studio .

Delete bin and obj folder on windows side.

Reconnect mac agent .

Clean and rebuild .

Change simulator(iPhone X e,g)

Disable remote simulator to Windows (Tools - Options - Xamarin - iOS Settings)

If problem persists , attach your build log here (Help - Xamarin - Open Logs).
(https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/176150/simulator-doesnt-show-up)